# DATE_FORMAT not working in insert statement

Tags: mysql

I have some timestamps that I receive in the format like

> 2018-02-26T23:59:49Z

I want to insert this date into a datetime column. Executing the following statement works

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2018-02-26T23:59:49Z', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s');
```

where the second argument is the result of

```
select @@datetime_format;
```

however, the following statement fails

```
    INSERT INTO
        my_db.my_table(
            my_datetime
        )
    VALUES
        (DATE_FORMAT('2018-02-26Т23:59:49Z', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
```

with the error

> Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect datetime value:
>   '2018-02-26T23:59:49Z'

Does `DATE_FORMAT` not work in insert statements like this?

Comment: Why are you using date_format like this?

Comment: The statement that fails is being executed by a program. In the place of the literal, there is a placeholder that is replaced with a calculated value

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with str_to_date :

```
 INSERT INTO
        my_db.my_table(
            my_datetime
        )
    VALUES
        (STR_TO_DATE('2018-02-26 23:59:49Z', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'));
```

Or try this :

```
INSERT INTO
            my_db.my_table(
                my_datetime
            )
VALUES
  (STR_TO_DATE(substring_index('2018-02-26 23:59:49Z', 'Z', 1),
                                 '%Y-%m-%d %h.%i.%s'));
```

Comment: it means you don't have exactly '2018-02-26 23:59:49Z' so i add a substring_index. It should work now.

Comment: I do not like this string based solution, as tomorrow the format might change and (either db-wise or or data-wise) and this would make it invalid

Comment: the ''2018-02-26 23:59:49Z' works perfectly with my 1st solution or the code in your question, here it's means you have some space or other code character that you don't see but it's in there. If you want you can try a trim in place of the substring_index

Answer (score 0):

check this-

```
 set  @date1 = from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2018-02-26 23:59:49Z'));
 INSERT INTO
            mytable(
                my_datetime
            )
        VALUES
            (@date1);
```